# In powerpoint how do I go about having looping animations?

Tags: loops, button, click, jquery-animate, powerpoint

I'm trying to animate a button so that if it is clicked, a picture will appear, but when it is clicked again, the picture will disappear- I want this to continue to happen indefinitely- I feel like this can easily be written with a macro, but I want to avoid unnecessary over-complicating of things. I tried to add in click animations but it will only appear and then disappear

Comment: Try adding in a loop to return to the previous slide then advance, essentially starting the animation over again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using animations, you can toggle the transparency of the image between 0 (totally transparent) and 1 (totally solid) when click happens to achieve disappearing and appearing.